# Does a car moving normally (using the engine ) has a force that can be calculated with its acceleration?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration

I would like to know if the force of a moving car can be calculated by using its acceleration or its mass by gravity

F = ma
F=mg
I support the idea of using F=ma but my teacher thinks F=mg , I want to know what's correct , his argument is that is not being pulled or pushed , but I think he should consider the first law of Newton

Comment: F=mg is used for vertical free fall ("a" is replaced with "g," (the natural acceleration of free fall near the surface of the earth))

You can use F=ma for horizontal accelerations, but g will not be used in this case.

Comment: What does he mean by "force of a moving car?"

Comment: Its early level physics. Where the force supplied by the engine is supposed to be mass of the car multiplied by its acceleration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the car is moving horizontally then there is no vertical force or mg= N

And F=ma for horizontal direction where F is the total horizontal force (  friction on tyres+ air resistance) & a the total horizontal acceleration

Comment: Thanks ! , I guess my teacher should review his notes lol

Comment: @AngeloGiuseppe Don't know he might be saying something else but in a confusing way. Anyway this is correct

Comment: @AngeloGiuseppe Welcome !

Comment: @HughMungus Actually I used friction to mean any sliding friction if there is any and engine for  the friction on the tyres which makes them move ( because it's engine which accelerates the tyre ). Though yes the external force is obviously the friction on the tyres which causes the motion. I guess my usage of engine was not good and I have edited it .

Comment: @HughMungus Would it really have been appropriate for Shashaank to go into that much detail, considering the OP doesn't really get how F=ma works?

Comment: @HughMungus Thanks its ok. It was a serious fault a very bad and confusing usage by me. I should have been careful

Comment: @Tobi The op says he considers supporting ma so I guessed he knew F=ma and I included all the forces to stress on the fact that acceleration is constant.